# TextField.text is not working after ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, viewdidload

I want to fill the `UITextField` after `viewDidLoad`, but after `viewDidLoad` I assign the `UITextField` does not appear in any appreciable way. 
I do this in `viewDidLoad` `UITextField` process;

```
_TextField.delegate = self;
```

Idle (after viewDidLoad)

```
_TextField.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:0]; // listarray is full
[_TextField setText:@"aaa"]; // The second way : not working
```

Need some guidance on what could be going wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: is your textfield visible in view?

Comment: Can you check `NSLog(@"TextField : %@", _TextField);` and see whether or not _TextField is `nil`.

Comment: Yes, of course it looks(page first loads just do not assign a value to TextField)

Comment: @Krishnabhadra After you assign a value, `textField: (null)` returns. So, do not be disposed of in any way that value into the TextField.

Comment: In which method are you assigning value to the textfield? can you show more code? Are you using the XIB approach or the code approach to show the textfield if its code then did you do [self.view addSubview:yourtextfield];. Also don't forget to set the frames and border of textfield if the textfield is added programmatically

Comment: if you do this in viewDidLoad, you just do it in     viewDidLoad, not after     viewDidLoad. If you want to do it after     viewDidLoad do it in     viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Comment: check your textfield textColor...

Comment: Its a week refrence as you have used it by the `_textfield.`  make it synthesise and then use the it as `textfield` . It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check whether the textfield text colour is not the same as its background.
2. Remove : `_TextField.delegate = self;`.
3. Check the storyboard textfield is connected properly where you defined `@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * TextField;`